# How to close Google account on the phone

Tags: samsung, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-account, samsung-apps

I let my friend borrow my Android phone. She never returned the phone and she is still using my account. Please, help me.

Answer (score 5):

Sign in to your account [here](https://myaccount.google.com/) and delete it like that:

[image: manage account]

More info on deletion you can find in [help article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en).
After the successful deletion your account will be signed out from the phone as well and your friend will lose the opportunity to use it.

If you want not to delete the account per se, but to delete it from phone (i.e. log out) without physical access to the phone, you can try to use [Device Activity tab](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) and revoke access there:

[image: remove device access]